# GraphQL query works in graphiQL playground but not postman

Tags: graphql, postman

The query works in graphiql but not in postman.

There's really not much more to say, it's self explaining, yet I have to bulk this out with more text because SO won't let me post the question otherwise.

Running on golang gql

query

```
mutation CreateAnswer($answer: NewAnswer!) {
  createAnswer(input: $answer) {
    id
    key
    value
  }
}
```

variables

```
{
    "answer": {
        "key": "this3",
        "value": "that"
    }
}
```

Postman error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "no operation provided",
            "extensions": {
                "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": null
}
```

Comment: pls extend your post with the actual JSON payload from Postman

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the http method to POST.

It doesn't auto-set this, even though all graphql queries are POST.